# Is there a web call or some sort of meta api to get all new comments in the last N hours?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

Is there an undocumented web call or some sort of meta API to get all new comments globally in the last N hours?

Comment: kinda like the twitter "firehose"? http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ#Whenwillthefirehosebeready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no.

There is a comment based tool in the 10k toolkit where you can see the most commented questions today and in the last 2-7-14-30 days

Comment: That sucks, cause if it was there I could engineer some sort of messaging on top of comments.

Comment: Huh? But there have been many requests for an API.

Comment: im not asking for a full api, just an html page that lists all the comments in the last N hours capped at a limit of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

If you view source the page you can see how the comments are fetched. You can only fetch comments for one question at a time, but as long as you weren't fetching them too frequently
you could write something to poll each id and update a count. You'd need to also monitor the questions so you would know if they were on questions or answers and what the title of the question was.

Comment: does posting a comment always touch the post and bump it to the top?

Comment: I believe only editing the question or answers affect bumping